# Can't disable Oracle foreign key over JDBC

Tags: java, spring, oracle, jdbctemplate, oracle18c

The following SQL-Script works perfectly within my SQL-Developer:

```
begin
  for c in (select * from user_constraints where constraint_type = 'R' and status = 'ENABLED')
  loop
    dbms_utility.exec_ddl_statement('alter table "' || c.owner || '"."' || c.table_name || '" disable constraint ' || c.constraint_name);
  end loop;
end;
```

When the same script is execute with the Spring JdbcTemplate, nothing is happening:

```
String sql = null;
try {
sql = FileUtils.readFileToString(resourceLoader.getResource("classpath:sql/DisableContraints.sql").getFile(), Charset.defaultCharset());
} catch (IOException e) {
   exceptionHandler.handleException("DisableContraints.sql not loaded.", e);
}
jdbcTemplate.execute(sql);
```

Same strange behaviour occours when I try to select the foreign keys: `select * from user_constraints where constraint_type = 'R' and status = 'ENABLED'`. SQL-Developer returns 32 Keys, JDBC returns 0. But when I select all keys (`select * from user_constraints where status = 'ENABLED'`) SQL-Developer and JDBC returns 68 keys.

I have no clue wheres the mistake.

Comment: Are you certain that the getResources() and readFileToString() calls are doing what you expect? Consider logging the value of `sql` just before the execute() call.  Is it possible that an exception is occurring, but getting caught, inside execute()?

Comment: Yes I checked the sql variable. It contains the content of the file.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have a different user/schema?

Try maybe:

```
select * from dba_constraints where constraint_type = 'R' and status = 'ENABLED' and owner = 'MYSCHEMA';
```

Don't forget the owner check, you don't want to disable `SYSTEM`- checks.

Comment: If one has code that isn't doing what one expects, running it in a DBA schema doesn't seem like a good idea.